# 301 Redirect in Azure

Tags: azure, redirect, asp.net-core

This has probably been asked many times, but I have a purchased domain (through 1&1 if that matters) foobar.com. I have setup custom domains in Azure and domain to forward to an azure app service I built, and that is working fine when someone goes to foobar.com. What I am seeing is if someone goes to www.foobar.com. they get an ugly web app not found (an Azure screen). What do I need to setup to make this redirect work. Do I need to update the domain/azure in someway? I have the following rule in my Web.config

```
 <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect old-domain to new-domain" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.foobar.com$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://foobar.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
```

Comment: You got foobar.com?!?!? Hats off to you. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always solve this with CNAME not through web.config. Take a look if you followed the steps described in here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-custom-domain-name-portal